# Twain causes out of memory error in wpf application

Tags: wpf, twain

I am working on a project which archive documents with many images as files or scanned images, it was working good until one of the customers decided to scan his images with high quality and colored.
Now the application exits with out of memory error and as I monitored computer resources, I found out that it was using so much memory, up to 1.4 gig in cases. Then I used /LARGEADDRESSAWARE to let it use as much as it wants and now it uses all of ram memory if necessary which leads to out of memory error again.
The thing is when I use scanner default application (Avision) it uses less than 400 MB of ram and does all the scans successfully.

I am using Saraff.Twain for handling scanner and I have written my own class to handle Saraff.Twain events as I want like below:

```
using Tools;
using System;
using Saraff.Twain;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Notary
{
    public class ScannerHandler
    {
        static Twain32 twain = new Twain32();
        public static event ScannerEventHandler ScannerEvent;
        public delegate void ScannerEventHandler(object sender, List<string> pathes);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr value);

        public ScannerHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                twain.OpenDSM();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Accessories.ErrorHandler(e, true);
            }
            twain.ShowUI = true;
            twain.AcquireCompleted += AcquireCompleted;
        }

        private static void AcquireCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ScannerEvent != null)
                {
                    List<string> output = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < twain.ImageCount; i++)
                    {
                        string temp = Accessories.GenerateTempAddress("jpg");
                        twain.GetImage(i).Save(temp, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        output.Add(temp);
                    }
                    ScannerEvent.Invoke(sender, output);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Accessories.ErrorHandler(ex, true);
            }
        }

        public static void Acquire()
        {
            try
            {
                twain.Acquire();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Accessories.ErrorHandler(e, true);
            }
        }

        ~ScannerHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                twain.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Accessories.ErrorHandler(e, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when scanner finishes, so I thought the problem is with how saraff.dll works, or am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to Acquire Images one by one?
Should I use any other dll for scanner in order to manage memory better?

Comment: How about *not* keeping so many images in memory? And actually disposing the `Bitmap` object, not just the pointer to it? The waste is caused by your own code - the Twain class stores all images in memory even though it doesn't need to. Then you create multiple Bitmap, Image objects just to write the images out to a JPG.

Comment: `Twain32.GetImage` returns an Image that already has a [Save()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can use to save to JPEG. You don't need to copy it to another image (Bitmap inherits from Image) or use an ImageSource

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried what you said, It still uses more than 1.4 gig of RAM when scanning is done and causes out of memory

Comment: It will, if you keep all the images in memory. Besides - what did you try? Where is the code?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question, removed creating bitmaps and used GetImage(index).save() instead